# Laravel validation URL failing even with sometimes perimeter set

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm running into an issue with Larvel 5.8 where the validation rules, specifically URL and my custom MACAddress rule are being triggered regardless if the request-type variable is set (based on the required_if).

I even attempted to update the URL rule to reference the "sometimes" vs the required if but no change. I always see the response "The url format is invalid." even if it is not required.

```
return [
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'reference-id' => 'required',
    'request-by-date' => 'required|date',
    'request-type' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required',
    'customer' => 'required|exists:customers,id',
    'url' => 'url|required_if:request-type,url|unique:requests,url,approved,1',
    'ip' => 'required_if:request-type,IP',
    'mac-address' => ['required_if:request-type,DHCPReservation', new MACAddress],
    'dhcp-device-type' => 'required_if:request-type,DHCPReservation',
    'other-device-type' => 'required_if:dhcp-device-type,Other'
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer by adding the **nullable** validation as shown below. Since it is a text field that is hidden on the field (unless the correct dropdown is shown) it seems the browser doesn't pass the empty string I expected it to.

```
'url' => 'required_if:request-type,url|nullable|url|unique:requests,url,approved,1',
```